# TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, finance, analysis, stock, datetimeindex

all!
I am trying to generate results of this repo

> https://github.com/ArnaudBu/stock-returns-prediction

for stocks price prediction based on financial analysis. Running the very first step

> 1_get_data.py

I come across an error: **TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex**

The code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from yfinance import Ticker
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import pickle

# with open('tmp.pickle', 'rb') as f:
#     statements, tickers_done = pickle.load(f)


# Download function
def _download_one(ticker, start=None, end=None,
                  auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False,
                  actions=False, period="max", interval="1d",
                  prepost=False, proxy=None, rounding=False):

    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
                                  start=start, end=end, prepost=prepost,
                                  actions=actions, auto_adjust=auto_adjust,
                                  back_adjust=back_adjust, proxy=proxy,
                                  rounding=rounding, many=True)


# Modify project and reference index according to your needs
tickers_all = []
# for project in ["sp500", "nyse", "nasdaq"]:
for project in ["nasdaq"]:
    print(project)
    ref_index = ["^GSPC", "^IXIC"]

    # Load tickers
    companies = pd.read_csv(f"data/{project}/{project}.csv", sep=",")
    # companies = companies.drop(companies.index[companies['Symbol'].index[companies['Symbol'].isnull()][0]]) # the row with Nan value
    tickers = companies.Symbol.tolist()
    tickers = [a for a in tickers if a not in tickers_all and "^" not in a and r"/" not in a]
    tickers_all += tickers

    # Download prices
    full_data = {}
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers + ref_index):
        tckr = _download_one(ticker,
                             period="7y",
                             actions=True)
        full_data[ticker] = tckr
    ohlc = pd.concat(full_data.values(), axis=1,
                     keys=full_data.keys())
    ohlc.columns = ohlc.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
    ohlc.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
    prices = ohlc["Adj Close"]
    dividends = ohlc["Dividends"]
    prices.to_csv(f"data/{project}/prices_daily.csv")
    dividends.to_csv(f"data/{project}/dividends.csv")

    statements = {}
    tickers_done = []
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers):
        # Get statements
        if ticker in tickers_done:
            continue
        yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
        stmts_codes = ['income', 'cash', 'balance']
        all_statement_data = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual',
                                                                  stmts_codes)
        # build statements dictionary
        for a in all_statement_data.keys():
            if a not in statements:
                statements[a] = list()
            for b in all_statement_data[a]:
                try:
                    for result in all_statement_data[a][b]:
                        extracted_date = list(result)[0]
                        dataframe_row = list(result.values())[0]
                        dataframe_row['date'] = extracted_date
                        dataframe_row['symbol'] = b
                        statements[a].append(dataframe_row)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error on " + ticker + " : " + a)
        tickers_done.append(ticker)
        with open('tmp.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump([statements, tickers_done], f)

    # save dataframes
    for a in all_statement_data.keys():
        df = pd.DataFrame(statements[a]).set_index('date')
        df.to_csv(f"data/{project}/{a}.csv")

    # Donwload shares
    shares = []
    tickers_done = []
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers):
        if ticker in tickers_done:
            continue
        d = requests.get(f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/{ticker}?symbol={ticker}&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber&merge=false&period1=0&period2=2013490868")
        if not d.ok:
            time.sleep(300)
            d = requests.get(f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/{ticker}?symbol={ticker}&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber&merge=false&period1=0&period2=2013490868")
        ctn = d.json()['timeseries']['result']
        dct = dict()
        for n in ctn:
            type = n['meta']['type'][0]
            dct[type] = dict()
            if type in n:
                for o in n[type]:
                    if o is not None:
                        dct[type][o['asOfDate']] = o['reportedValue']['raw']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)
        df['symbol'] = ticker
        shares.append(df)
        tickers_done.append(ticker)
        time.sleep(1)

    # save dataframe
    df = pd.concat(shares)
    df['date'] = df.index
    df.to_csv(f"data/{project}/shares.csv", index=False)

    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/MSFT?symbol=MSFT&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualTreasurySharesNumber,trailingTreasurySharesNumber,annualPreferredSharesNumber,trailingPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber,trailingOrdinarySharesNumber,annualShareIssued,trailingShareIssued,annualNetDebt,trailingNetDebt,annualTotalDebt,trailingTotalDebt,annualTangibleBookValue,trailingTangibleBookValue,annualInvestedCapital,trailingInvestedCapital,annualWorkingCapital,trailingWorkingCapital,annualNetTangibleAssets,trailingNetTangibleAssets,annualCapitalLeaseObligations,trailingCapitalLeaseObligations,annualCommonStockEquity,trailingCommonStockEquity,annualPreferredStockEquity,trailingPreferredStockEquity,annualTotalCapitalization,trailingTotalCapitalization,annualTotalEquityGrossMinorityInterest,trailingTotalEquityGrossMinorityInterest,annualMinorityInterest,trailingMinorityInterest,annualStockholdersEquity,trailingStockholdersEquity,annualOtherEquityInterest,trailingOtherEquityInterest,annualGainsLossesNotAffectingRetainedEarnings,trailingGainsLossesNotAffectingRetainedEarnings,annualOtherEquityAdjustments,trailingOtherEquityAdjustments,annualFixedAssetsRevaluationReserve,trailingFixedAssetsRevaluationReserve,annualForeignCurrencyTranslationAdjustments,trailingForeignCurrencyTranslationAdjustments,annualMinimumPensionLiabilities,trailingMinimumPensionLiabilities,annualUnrealizedGainLoss,trailingUnrealizedGainLoss,annualTreasuryStock,trailingTreasuryStock,annualRetainedEarnings,trailingRetainedEarnings,annualAdditionalPaidInCapital,trailingAdditionalPaidInCapital,annualCapitalStock,trailingCapitalStock,annualOtherCapitalStock,trailingOtherCapitalStock,annualCommonStock,trailingCommonStock,annualPreferredStock,trailingPreferredStock,annualTotalPartnershipCapital,trailingTotalPartnershipCapital,annualGeneralPartnershipCapital,trailingGeneralPartnershipCapital,annualLimitedPartnershipCapital,trailingLimitedPartnershipCapital,annualTotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,trailingTotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,annualTotalNonCurrentLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,trailingTotalNonCurrentLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,annualOtherNonCurrentLiabilities,trailingOtherNonCurrentLiabilities,annualLiabilitiesHeldforSaleNonCurrent,trailingLiabilitiesHeldforSaleNonCurrent,annualRestrictedCommonStock,trailingRestrictedCommonStock,annualPreferredSecuritiesOutsideStockEquity,trailingPreferredSecuritiesOutsideStockEquity,annualDerivativeProductLiabilities,trailingDerivativeProductLiabilities,annualEmployeeBenefits,trailingEmployeeBenefits,annualNonCurrentPensionAndOtherPostretirementBenefitPlans,trailingNonCurrentPensionAndOtherPostretirementBenefitPlans,annualNonCurrentAccruedExpenses,trailingNonCurrentAccruedExpenses,annualDuetoRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,trailingDuetoRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,annualTradeandOtherPayablesNonCurrent,trailingTradeandOtherPayablesNonCurrent,annualNonCurrentDeferredLiabilities,trailingNonCurrentDeferredLiabilities,annualNonCurrentDeferredRevenue,trailingNonCurrentDeferredRevenue,annualNonCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,trailingNonCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,annualLongTermDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingLongTermDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,annualLongTermCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingLongTermCapitalLeaseObligation,annualLongTermDebt,trailingLongTermDebt,annualLongTermProvisions,trailingLongTermProvisions,annualCurrentLiabilities,trailingCurrentLiabilities,annualOtherCurrentLiabilities,trailingOtherCurrentLiabilities,annualCurrentDeferredLiabilities,trailingCurrentDeferredLiabilities,annualCurrentDeferredRevenue,trailingCurrentDeferredRevenue,annualCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,trailingCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,annualCurrentDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingCurrentDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,annualCurrentCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingCurrentCapitalLeaseObligation,annualCurrentDebt,trailingCurrentDebt,annualOtherCurrentBorrowings,trailingOtherCurrentBorrowings,annualLineOfCredit,trailingLineOfCredit,annualCommercialPaper,trailingCommercialPaper,annualCurrentNotesPayable,trailingCurrentNotesPayable,annualPensionandOtherPostRetirementBenefitPlansCurrent,trailingPensionandOtherPostRetirementBenefitPlansCurrent,annualCurrentProvisions,trailingCurrentProvisions,annualPayablesAndAccruedExpenses,trailingPayablesAndAccruedExpenses,annualCurrentAccruedExpenses,trailingCurrentAccruedExpenses,annualInterestPayable,trailingInterestPayable,annualPayables,trailingPayables,annualOtherPayable,trailingOtherPayable,annualDuetoRelatedPartiesCurrent,trailingDuetoRelatedPartiesCurrent,annualDividendsPayable,trailingDividendsPayable,annualTotalTaxPayable,trailingTotalTaxPayable,annualIncomeTaxPayable,trailingIncomeTaxPayable,annualAccountsPayable,trailingAccountsPayable,annualTotalAssets,trailingTotalAssets,annualTotalNonCurrentAssets,trailingTotalNonCurrentAssets,annualOtherNonCurrentAssets,trailingOtherNonCurrentAssets,annualDefinedPensionBenefit,trailingDefinedPensionBenefit,annualNonCurrentPrepaidAssets,trailingNonCurrentPrepaidAssets,annualNonCurrentDeferredAssets,trailingNonCurrentDeferredAssets,annualNonCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,trailingNonCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,annualDuefromRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,trailingDuefromRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,annualNonCurrentNoteReceivables,trailingNonCurrentNoteReceivables,annualNonCurrentAccountsReceivable,trailingNonCurrentAccountsReceivable,annualFinancialAssets,trailingFinancialAssets,annualInvestmentsAndAdvances,trailingInvestmentsAndAdvances,annualOtherInvestments,trailingOtherInvestments,annualInvestmentinFinancialAssets,trailingInvestmentinFinancialAssets,annualHeldToMaturitySecurities,trailingHeldToMaturitySecurities,annualAvailableForSaleSecurities,trailingAvailableForSaleSecurities,annualFinancialAssetsDesignatedasFairValueThroughProfitorLossTotal,trailingFinancialAssetsDesignatedasFairValueThroughProfitorLossTotal,annualTradingSecurities,trailingTradingSecurities,annualLongTermEquityInvestment,trailingLongTermEquityInvestment,annualInvestmentsinJointVenturesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinJointVenturesatCost,annualInvestmentsInOtherVenturesUnderEquityMethod,trailingInvestmentsInOtherVenturesUnderEquityMethod,annualInvestmentsinAssociatesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinAssociatesatCost,annualInvestmentsinSubsidiariesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinSubsidiariesatCost,annualInvestmentProperties,trailingInvestmentProperties,annualGoodwillAndOtherIntangibleAssets,trailingGoodwillAndOtherIntangibleAssets,annualOtherIntangibleAssets,trailingOtherIntangibleAssets,annualGoodwill,trailingGoodwill,annualNetPPE,trailingNetPPE,annualAccumulatedDepreciation,trailingAccumulatedDepreciation,annualGrossPPE,trailingGrossPPE,annualLeases,trailingLeases,annualConstructionInProgress,trailingConstructionInProgress,annualOtherProperties,trailingOtherProperties,annualMachineryFurnitureEquipment,trailingMachineryFurnitureEquipment,annualBuildingsAndImprovements,trailingBuildingsAndImprovements,annualLandAndImprovements,trailingLandAndImprovements,annualProperties,trailingProperties,annualCurrentAssets,trailingCurrentAssets,annualOtherCurrentAssets,trailingOtherCurrentAssets,annualHedgingAssetsCurrent,trailingHedgingAssetsCurrent,annualAssetsHeldForSaleCurrent,trailingAssetsHeldForSaleCurrent,annualCurrentDeferredAssets,trailingCurrentDeferredAssets,annualCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,trailingCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,annualRestrictedCash,trailingRestrictedCash,annualPrepaidAssets,trailingPrepaidAssets,annualInventory,trailingInventory,annualInventoriesAdjustmentsAllowances,trailingInventoriesAdjustmentsAllowances,annualOtherInventories,trailingOtherInventories,annualFinishedGoods,trailingFinishedGoods,annualWorkInProcess,trailingWorkInProcess,annualRawMaterials,trailingRawMaterials,annualReceivables,trailingReceivables,annualReceivablesAdjustmentsAllowances,trailingReceivablesAdjustmentsAllowances,annualOtherReceivables,trailingOtherReceivables,annualDuefromRelatedPartiesCurrent,trailingDuefromRelatedPartiesCurrent,annualTaxesReceivable,trailingTaxesReceivable,annualAccruedInterestReceivable,trailingAccruedInterestReceivable,annualNotesReceivable,trailingNotesReceivable,annualLoansReceivable,trailingLoansReceivable,annualAccountsReceivable,trailingAccountsReceivable,annualAllowanceForDoubtfulAccountsReceivable,trailingAllowanceForDoubtfulAccountsReceivable,annualGrossAccountsReceivable,trailingGrossAccountsReceivable,annualCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,trailingCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,annualOtherShortTermInvestments,trailingOtherShortTermInvestments,annualCashAndCashEquivalents,trailingCashAndCashEquivalents,annualCashEquivalents,trailingCashEquivalents,annualCashFinancial,trailingCashFinancial&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1613490868
    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/MSFT?symbol=MSFT&period1=1550725200&period2=1613491890&useYfid=true&interval=1d&events=div
    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/MSFT?formatted=true&crumb=2M1BZy1YB7f&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistory,cashflowStatementHistory,balanceSheetHistory,incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly,cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly,balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com
```

The screenshot of the error is:

[image: Error Screenshot]

It refers to the **line 51** of the above code. I have tried multiple times, and check some related questions/answers here as well but have not any satisfied answer. There is another similar question but it has not any proper answer.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that the issue was related to the **full_data[ticker]** in line 49. Once I checked its type and data inside, I found it as dataframe and as:

[image]

The issue was with the time under the index column **Date**. So, to remove those I used this line `full_data[ticker] = full_data[ticker].tz_localize(None)`  of code under the line 49 `full_data[ticker] = tckr`. And then I checked the **full_data[ticker]** so got this:

[image]

The time under the **Date** are disappeared hence solving the issue. Thanks to @VasP whose suggestion helped me to crack this issue.

So, here is the working code now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from yfinance import Ticker
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import pickle

# with open('tmp.pickle', 'rb') as f:
#     statements, tickers_done = pickle.load(f)


# Download function
def _download_one(ticker, start=None, end=None,
                  auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False,
                  actions=False, period="max", interval="1d",
                  prepost=False, proxy=None, rounding=False):

    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
                                  start=start, end=end, prepost=prepost,
                                  actions=actions, auto_adjust=auto_adjust,
                                  back_adjust=back_adjust, proxy=proxy,
                                  rounding=rounding, many=True)


# Modify project and reference index according to your needs
tickers_all = []
# for project in ["sp500", "nyse", "nasdaq"]:
for project in ["nasdaq"]:
    print(project)
    ref_index = ["^GSPC", "^IXIC"]

    # Load tickers
    companies = pd.read_csv(f"data/{project}/{project}.csv", sep=",")
    # companies = companies.drop(companies.index[companies['Symbol'].index[companies['Symbol'].isnull()][0]]) # the row with Nan value
    tickers = companies.Symbol.tolist()
    tickers = [a for a in tickers if a not in tickers_all and "^" not in a and r"/" not in a]
    tickers_all += tickers

    # Download prices
    full_data = {}
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers + ref_index):
        tckr = _download_one(ticker,
                             period="7y",
                             actions=True)
        full_data[ticker] = tckr
        full_data[ticker] = full_data[ticker].tz_localize(None)    #Added now
    ohlc = pd.concat(full_data.values(), axis=1,
                     keys=full_data.keys())
    ohlc.columns = ohlc.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
    ohlc.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
    prices = ohlc["Adj Close"]
    dividends = ohlc["Dividends"]
    prices.to_csv(f"data/{project}/prices_daily.csv")
    dividends.to_csv(f"data/{project}/dividends.csv")

    statements = {}
    tickers_done = []
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers):
        # Get statements
        if ticker in tickers_done:
            continue
        yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
        stmts_codes = ['income', 'cash', 'balance']
        all_statement_data = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual',
                                                                  stmts_codes)
        # build statements dictionary
        for a in all_statement_data.keys():
            if a not in statements:
                statements[a] = list()
            for b in all_statement_data[a]:
                try:
                    for result in all_statement_data[a][b]:
                        extracted_date = list(result)[0]
                        dataframe_row = list(result.values())[0]
                        dataframe_row['date'] = extracted_date
                        dataframe_row['symbol'] = b
                        statements[a].append(dataframe_row)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error on " + ticker + " : " + a)
        tickers_done.append(ticker)
        with open('tmp.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump([statements, tickers_done], f)

    # save dataframes
    for a in all_statement_data.keys():
        df = pd.DataFrame(statements[a]).set_index('date')
        df.to_csv(f"data/{project}/{a}.csv")

    # Donwload shares
    shares = []
    tickers_done = []
    for ticker in tqdm(tickers):
        if ticker in tickers_done:
            continue
        d = requests.get(f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/{ticker}?symbol={ticker}&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber&merge=false&period1=0&period2=2013490868")
        if not d.ok:
            time.sleep(300)
            d = requests.get(f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/{ticker}?symbol={ticker}&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber&merge=false&period1=0&period2=2013490868")
        ctn = d.json()['timeseries']['result']
        dct = dict()
        for n in ctn:
            type = n['meta']['type'][0]
            dct[type] = dict()
            if type in n:
                for o in n[type]:
                    if o is not None:
                        dct[type][o['asOfDate']] = o['reportedValue']['raw']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)
        df['symbol'] = ticker
        shares.append(df)
        tickers_done.append(ticker)
        time.sleep(1)

    # save dataframe
    df = pd.concat(shares)
    df['date'] = df.index
    df.to_csv(f"data/{project}/shares.csv", index=False)

    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/MSFT?symbol=MSFT&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualTreasurySharesNumber,trailingTreasurySharesNumber,annualPreferredSharesNumber,trailingPreferredSharesNumber,annualOrdinarySharesNumber,trailingOrdinarySharesNumber,annualShareIssued,trailingShareIssued,annualNetDebt,trailingNetDebt,annualTotalDebt,trailingTotalDebt,annualTangibleBookValue,trailingTangibleBookValue,annualInvestedCapital,trailingInvestedCapital,annualWorkingCapital,trailingWorkingCapital,annualNetTangibleAssets,trailingNetTangibleAssets,annualCapitalLeaseObligations,trailingCapitalLeaseObligations,annualCommonStockEquity,trailingCommonStockEquity,annualPreferredStockEquity,trailingPreferredStockEquity,annualTotalCapitalization,trailingTotalCapitalization,annualTotalEquityGrossMinorityInterest,trailingTotalEquityGrossMinorityInterest,annualMinorityInterest,trailingMinorityInterest,annualStockholdersEquity,trailingStockholdersEquity,annualOtherEquityInterest,trailingOtherEquityInterest,annualGainsLossesNotAffectingRetainedEarnings,trailingGainsLossesNotAffectingRetainedEarnings,annualOtherEquityAdjustments,trailingOtherEquityAdjustments,annualFixedAssetsRevaluationReserve,trailingFixedAssetsRevaluationReserve,annualForeignCurrencyTranslationAdjustments,trailingForeignCurrencyTranslationAdjustments,annualMinimumPensionLiabilities,trailingMinimumPensionLiabilities,annualUnrealizedGainLoss,trailingUnrealizedGainLoss,annualTreasuryStock,trailingTreasuryStock,annualRetainedEarnings,trailingRetainedEarnings,annualAdditionalPaidInCapital,trailingAdditionalPaidInCapital,annualCapitalStock,trailingCapitalStock,annualOtherCapitalStock,trailingOtherCapitalStock,annualCommonStock,trailingCommonStock,annualPreferredStock,trailingPreferredStock,annualTotalPartnershipCapital,trailingTotalPartnershipCapital,annualGeneralPartnershipCapital,trailingGeneralPartnershipCapital,annualLimitedPartnershipCapital,trailingLimitedPartnershipCapital,annualTotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,trailingTotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,annualTotalNonCurrentLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,trailingTotalNonCurrentLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest,annualOtherNonCurrentLiabilities,trailingOtherNonCurrentLiabilities,annualLiabilitiesHeldforSaleNonCurrent,trailingLiabilitiesHeldforSaleNonCurrent,annualRestrictedCommonStock,trailingRestrictedCommonStock,annualPreferredSecuritiesOutsideStockEquity,trailingPreferredSecuritiesOutsideStockEquity,annualDerivativeProductLiabilities,trailingDerivativeProductLiabilities,annualEmployeeBenefits,trailingEmployeeBenefits,annualNonCurrentPensionAndOtherPostretirementBenefitPlans,trailingNonCurrentPensionAndOtherPostretirementBenefitPlans,annualNonCurrentAccruedExpenses,trailingNonCurrentAccruedExpenses,annualDuetoRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,trailingDuetoRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,annualTradeandOtherPayablesNonCurrent,trailingTradeandOtherPayablesNonCurrent,annualNonCurrentDeferredLiabilities,trailingNonCurrentDeferredLiabilities,annualNonCurrentDeferredRevenue,trailingNonCurrentDeferredRevenue,annualNonCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,trailingNonCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,annualLongTermDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingLongTermDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,annualLongTermCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingLongTermCapitalLeaseObligation,annualLongTermDebt,trailingLongTermDebt,annualLongTermProvisions,trailingLongTermProvisions,annualCurrentLiabilities,trailingCurrentLiabilities,annualOtherCurrentLiabilities,trailingOtherCurrentLiabilities,annualCurrentDeferredLiabilities,trailingCurrentDeferredLiabilities,annualCurrentDeferredRevenue,trailingCurrentDeferredRevenue,annualCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,trailingCurrentDeferredTaxesLiabilities,annualCurrentDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingCurrentDebtAndCapitalLeaseObligation,annualCurrentCapitalLeaseObligation,trailingCurrentCapitalLeaseObligation,annualCurrentDebt,trailingCurrentDebt,annualOtherCurrentBorrowings,trailingOtherCurrentBorrowings,annualLineOfCredit,trailingLineOfCredit,annualCommercialPaper,trailingCommercialPaper,annualCurrentNotesPayable,trailingCurrentNotesPayable,annualPensionandOtherPostRetirementBenefitPlansCurrent,trailingPensionandOtherPostRetirementBenefitPlansCurrent,annualCurrentProvisions,trailingCurrentProvisions,annualPayablesAndAccruedExpenses,trailingPayablesAndAccruedExpenses,annualCurrentAccruedExpenses,trailingCurrentAccruedExpenses,annualInterestPayable,trailingInterestPayable,annualPayables,trailingPayables,annualOtherPayable,trailingOtherPayable,annualDuetoRelatedPartiesCurrent,trailingDuetoRelatedPartiesCurrent,annualDividendsPayable,trailingDividendsPayable,annualTotalTaxPayable,trailingTotalTaxPayable,annualIncomeTaxPayable,trailingIncomeTaxPayable,annualAccountsPayable,trailingAccountsPayable,annualTotalAssets,trailingTotalAssets,annualTotalNonCurrentAssets,trailingTotalNonCurrentAssets,annualOtherNonCurrentAssets,trailingOtherNonCurrentAssets,annualDefinedPensionBenefit,trailingDefinedPensionBenefit,annualNonCurrentPrepaidAssets,trailingNonCurrentPrepaidAssets,annualNonCurrentDeferredAssets,trailingNonCurrentDeferredAssets,annualNonCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,trailingNonCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,annualDuefromRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,trailingDuefromRelatedPartiesNonCurrent,annualNonCurrentNoteReceivables,trailingNonCurrentNoteReceivables,annualNonCurrentAccountsReceivable,trailingNonCurrentAccountsReceivable,annualFinancialAssets,trailingFinancialAssets,annualInvestmentsAndAdvances,trailingInvestmentsAndAdvances,annualOtherInvestments,trailingOtherInvestments,annualInvestmentinFinancialAssets,trailingInvestmentinFinancialAssets,annualHeldToMaturitySecurities,trailingHeldToMaturitySecurities,annualAvailableForSaleSecurities,trailingAvailableForSaleSecurities,annualFinancialAssetsDesignatedasFairValueThroughProfitorLossTotal,trailingFinancialAssetsDesignatedasFairValueThroughProfitorLossTotal,annualTradingSecurities,trailingTradingSecurities,annualLongTermEquityInvestment,trailingLongTermEquityInvestment,annualInvestmentsinJointVenturesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinJointVenturesatCost,annualInvestmentsInOtherVenturesUnderEquityMethod,trailingInvestmentsInOtherVenturesUnderEquityMethod,annualInvestmentsinAssociatesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinAssociatesatCost,annualInvestmentsinSubsidiariesatCost,trailingInvestmentsinSubsidiariesatCost,annualInvestmentProperties,trailingInvestmentProperties,annualGoodwillAndOtherIntangibleAssets,trailingGoodwillAndOtherIntangibleAssets,annualOtherIntangibleAssets,trailingOtherIntangibleAssets,annualGoodwill,trailingGoodwill,annualNetPPE,trailingNetPPE,annualAccumulatedDepreciation,trailingAccumulatedDepreciation,annualGrossPPE,trailingGrossPPE,annualLeases,trailingLeases,annualConstructionInProgress,trailingConstructionInProgress,annualOtherProperties,trailingOtherProperties,annualMachineryFurnitureEquipment,trailingMachineryFurnitureEquipment,annualBuildingsAndImprovements,trailingBuildingsAndImprovements,annualLandAndImprovements,trailingLandAndImprovements,annualProperties,trailingProperties,annualCurrentAssets,trailingCurrentAssets,annualOtherCurrentAssets,trailingOtherCurrentAssets,annualHedgingAssetsCurrent,trailingHedgingAssetsCurrent,annualAssetsHeldForSaleCurrent,trailingAssetsHeldForSaleCurrent,annualCurrentDeferredAssets,trailingCurrentDeferredAssets,annualCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,trailingCurrentDeferredTaxesAssets,annualRestrictedCash,trailingRestrictedCash,annualPrepaidAssets,trailingPrepaidAssets,annualInventory,trailingInventory,annualInventoriesAdjustmentsAllowances,trailingInventoriesAdjustmentsAllowances,annualOtherInventories,trailingOtherInventories,annualFinishedGoods,trailingFinishedGoods,annualWorkInProcess,trailingWorkInProcess,annualRawMaterials,trailingRawMaterials,annualReceivables,trailingReceivables,annualReceivablesAdjustmentsAllowances,trailingReceivablesAdjustmentsAllowances,annualOtherReceivables,trailingOtherReceivables,annualDuefromRelatedPartiesCurrent,trailingDuefromRelatedPartiesCurrent,annualTaxesReceivable,trailingTaxesReceivable,annualAccruedInterestReceivable,trailingAccruedInterestReceivable,annualNotesReceivable,trailingNotesReceivable,annualLoansReceivable,trailingLoansReceivable,annualAccountsReceivable,trailingAccountsReceivable,annualAllowanceForDoubtfulAccountsReceivable,trailingAllowanceForDoubtfulAccountsReceivable,annualGrossAccountsReceivable,trailingGrossAccountsReceivable,annualCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,trailingCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,annualOtherShortTermInvestments,trailingOtherShortTermInvestments,annualCashAndCashEquivalents,trailingCashAndCashEquivalents,annualCashEquivalents,trailingCashEquivalents,annualCashFinancial,trailingCashFinancial&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1613490868
    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/MSFT?symbol=MSFT&period1=1550725200&period2=1613491890&useYfid=true&interval=1d&events=div
    # https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/MSFT?formatted=true&crumb=2M1BZy1YB7f&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistory,cashflowStatementHistory,balanceSheetHistory,incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly,cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly,balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not managed to reproduce your dataframes, but generally this type of error is easily removed by doing df.tz_localize(None).
This will convert a tz-aware df to a tz-naive df.
so try applying this to the full_data dataframe of yours.

Comment: Hi @VasP, thanks for the response. Since the full_data type is Dict hence it throws this error:

`----> 1 full_data.tz_localize(None)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'`